# Double Star Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

That probably isn't the right word for it, so if anyone could tell me what this data type is actually called, that would be appreciated.

I have a programming assignment in which I have to implement a hash map as an array of trailer linked lists, declared by the professor as such.

```
LN** map = nullptr;
```

Each index of the array is supposed to start off with the trailer node alone, and that's where I'm having problems. Whenever I try to double the length of the array, the code somehow puts a quantity of trailer nodes equal to the length of the array at index zero.  After I do a bunch of insertions, the hash map typically looks something like this.

```
// # Represents nullptr
// pair[,] is a trailer.
map m = bin[0]: pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> #
        bin[1]: pair[Shirley,Peanutbuttercup] -> pair[,] -> #
        bin[2]: pair[Nicholas,Kafka] -> pair[,] -> #
        bin[3]: pair[,] -> #
        bin[4]: pair[Sora,Phammyy] -> pair[,] -> #
        bin[5]: pair[Selv,Anthony] -> pair[,] -> #
        bin[6]: pair[,] -> #
        bin[7]: pair[,] -> #
```

Which is odd, considering my code for doubling the array is.

```
bins *= 2;
map = new LN*[bins];
for (int i=0; i<bins; i++) {
    map[i] = new LN(); 
}

while (!q.empty()) {
    Entry e = q.dequeue();
    int hash = hash_compress(e.first);
    map[hash] = new LN(e, map[hash]);
}
```

I don't expect anyone to be able to debug my code (though on the off chance that anyone could, that would be great) but I would appreciate it if anyone could explain this data type in detail so I could have a better shot at figuring out where I'm screwing up.

LN is defined as

```
private:
  class LN {
    public:
      LN ()                         : next(nullptr){}
      LN (const LN& ln)             : value(ln.value), next(ln.next){}
      LN (Entry v, LN* n = nullptr) : value(v), next(n){}

      Entry value;  // typedef ics::pair<KEY,T> Entry; declared earlier
      LN*   next;
  };
```

Comment: It's called a pointer to a pointer of LN. Or you could call it a 2D-pointer array of LN

Comment: Why don't you use std::vector<std::vector<LN>> instead? Is not using STL a requirement?

Comment: I would love to use something simpler, but we have to use the data types the professor gave us.

Comment: Your professor's idea of each index having a trailer node is academically *wrong*. Each slot in your primary pointer array contains a pointer to that hash-index collision list. If there are no entries *at all* in a specific index, i.e. *nothing* has hashed to that slot, there will be no collision list and the entry should be NULL. The initialization for-loop of dummy node pointers is neither needed nor advised. In short, NULL is a damn-fine value that says "this list is empty." Ideally, you load your initial pointer list with NULLs, not dummy nodes.

Comment: `map[hash] = new LN(e, map[hash]);` looks really odd.. You allocated memory at `map[i]` and now you're replacing it with new memory? You should probably call `delete` first? I don't know but it looks really odd seeing that line.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames its right as written. Though we can't see it (not posted code), the LN constructor takes the `next` pointer it is to consume as the second parameter, and that would be the *current* entry in the hash table at that index prior to the final assignment.

Comment: @Nicholas i have to ask, how is your table expansion code implemented. When expanding the table you need to rehash all existing entries, as they are not guaranteed to fall in the same index slots in the newly expanded map. (in fact, if implemented right, it is *unlikely* they will hash to the same slot since your hash function is table-size based). When expanding a hash table the simplest approach is to declare a new pointer list of the appropriate size, then move (via hash) the exiting nodes to the new table. A queue is not needed and frankly I'm not sure why you have one to begin with.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames. He's creating a linked list.

Comment: @WhozCraig I was putting the values from the old map into a queue, and putting the values from that queue into a new hash map with double the length of the previous one. I suppose the queue isn't really needed, but I found it simpler to implement than creating a new hash map as I was traversing the old one.

The hash function includes the line "return answer%bins;"

I know the the entries aren't supposed to land in the same indexes of the expanded hash maps, so the function already takes into account the number of bins in the array.

Comment: @Nicholas so `hash_compress` uses `bin` for its calculation internally? Is that correct?

Comment: @Nicholas, have you considered the input to hash_compress will result in a lot of 0's?

Comment: @Nicholas, if you return answer%bins, then that's the culprit. It will return a lot of 0's. Which is why you get a lot of empty entries in the first linked list. So I guess you got about 8 times more entries than bins.

Comment: @Nicholas ok. I strongly advise doing as I described and just allocating a new pointer array for your new table, moving the entries via rehash loop (walking each collision chain in each slot of the old table), then swapping the old table base pointer with the new and deleting the old (its going to be empty anyway). Its a straight-forward algorithm. Your profs "dummy node" concept is hideous and I *strongly* advise against it.

Comment: @JonPall The hash function works fine (notice how the non-empty entries in the sample map are pretty spread out), so if it weren't for the fact that I have to implement this map as an array of trailer linked lists I would have been just fine. The problem is that I'm getting excess trailers in the first index of the array for some reason.

Comment: I have one more question before posting an answer unless someone beats me to it. How do you access the "value" of a `LN` node? It should have two members (the value and the next pointer). What is the member name of the value field in an LN so it can be passed to your hash function?

Comment: @WhozCraig The"value" is a pair, comprising a key and the value associated with it, and the key is what gets passed to the hash function.

Comment: So the "value" of a LN is a `std::pair<>`, and the `first` is the hash-material? Mmmk. What is the name of the pair *field* in `LN ? (trying to get as close as possible to your actual code). Or just post the declaration of the LN node up in the question. I probably should have asked for that a long time ago. sry.

Comment: @Nicholas Every multiple of the number of bins is considered empty. Hence you see excess trailers.

Comment: @JonPall So you're saying that if I were to have an eighth bin (which would be impossible, given the length of the array) that multiple would be empty as well? I'm trying to understand that comment.

Comment: An array of pointers to arrays of possibly unequal lengths is called a **jagged array**. It's called that even when all lenghts are equal, i.e. a matrix. An array of arrays, in contrast, is called a **multidimensional array**. These are C terms, and in C they do not conflict very much with general Computer Science terminology. However, some context must be considered to be sure what's meant, and it doesn't hurt to explain what one means when using these terms.

Comment: @Nicholas. What I am saying is, either is the answer in "result answer%bins" 0, or a multiple of bins. Either way, you get too many resulting 0's, and by now is clear that the input results in "answer" to be 0. Do you by any chance have empty entries? If so, you need to check for them, if you want to leave them out of the map.

Comment: @Nicholas I believe you're incorrectly moving your old trailer nodes to your new list, and the all seem to hash to slot-0, so a new one shows up with each successive collision list you walk in the old map. Hopefully the posted answer makes sense on how to avoid it, and honestly I'd consider eliminating the whole "trailer node" concept entirely, as it literally buys you *nothing* at the cost of making the code more tedious .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your profs concept of a "trailer" node, the following code will do it. I advise *strongly* against the very idea of a "trailer" node, as it buys you *nothing* and just makes the list management more tedious. Your prof is essentially telling you to put something in what is *supposed* to be a *collision list*, yet the something your putting in never collided with anything. NULL is a fine end-of-list marker, and I advise you use it instead.

I believe the most important thing missing was accounting for **not** adding the trailer-nodes from the old map when building your new map. I'm believe they all mapped to slot zero, and you were blindly putting them into your new map. In other words, you were not ignoring the useless trailer nodes when rehashing your collision lists.

The code below is about as efficient as you're going to get this, requiring no intermediate queue, no node *copying*, and only rehashing of existing nodes that will be *moved* (their pointers) to the new table:

```
// double the size of the hash table. 
unsigned int old_bin = bin;
bin *= 2;
LN** new_map = new LN*[bin]();

// load new set of trailers into new map
for (unsigned int i=0; i<bin; ++i)
    new_map[i] = new LN();

// walk the old table (0..old_bin-1) rehashing and 
//  moving existing nodes to new slots in the hash table.
for (unsigned int i=0; i<old_bin; ++i)
{
    // without the "trailer node", this should just be (map[i])
    while (map[i]->next)
    {
        // pull node from old collision list at i
        LN *p = map[i];
        map[i] = p->next;

        // rehash to new table based on new table size
        unsigned int idx = hash_compress(p->value.first);
        p->next = new_map[idx];
        new_map[idx] = p;
    }

    // delete trailer node (better be the last one)
    delete map[i];
}

delete [] map;
map = new_map;
```

Thats it. This would be *considerably* cleaner without all the trailer-node insanity, but you can bring that up with your prof. Nearly half this code would disappear if you used NULL for your end-of-collision-list marker rather than some fictitious trailer node. I would respectfully as your prof why he thinks putting *anything* that is not a collision in a *collision list* is a good idea (because it isn't).

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH OKAY YOU'RE RIGHT. I was putting all of those trailers from the old maps into the queue, which was why I was getting all those excess trailers. Fixed the problem just now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
int hash = hash_compress(e.first);
```

You get a lot of hash values at 0. Do you check for empty input? How do you distinguish between valid and invalid input, if the hash is always considered to be valid.

As seen by your table.

```
map m = bin[0]: pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,] -> pair[,]
```

Your code

```
map[hash] = new LN(e, map[hash]);
```

is generating these, because e is empty and the hash value is therefore always 0. How else would they end up there?

Edit: and hence, the empty entries was the pre-existing "trailers" used as input...